# How block mails with certain content before moved to spam in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I am getting spam mails with always the same content (and the same subject). They are sent each time from a different address. Outlook always automatically puts them in the Spam folder. However, I want them to be deleted automatically. Therefore I made a rule which automatically deletes incoming mails with this specific subject. But the rule does not work because new mails with this subject are moved to the Spam folder by Outlook before the rule starts working. When I click on such a mail and say "never send this to spam", then the next mail is still moved to spam.

I also verified that the rule does work when I send a mail from some other address to my address containing the specific subject.

How can I stop Outlook from moving the mails to spam?

Comment: It's not possible if the email address keeps changing.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider taking the opposite method of white-listing these
junk emails, so they can get into the inbox where the delete rule
can catch them.

See also the article
[Applying message rules to the Junk E-mail folder](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/junkrules.htm),
where a VBA macro is listed that applies rules to the junk folder.
However, the macro requires manual activation by yourself and doesn't
run automatically.
If this interests you, see more details in
[this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-make-a-rule-to-automatically-delete-e-mails/c6a25e67-020b-4f33-92a4-3bb7fc5e880b).

Comment: Can I white-list those junk emails when they are from a different sender each time?

Comment: You will need to apply the same techniques as in my link by using VBA, because Outlook is very limited. Or you might opt for third-party spam solutions (google for "outlook spam filter alternatives").

Comment: I would like to run this automatically

Comment: Could it be possible to run the macro every 10 minutes with a google app-script?

Comment: Google app-script is not usable in Outlook. You would be looking into more like [Outlook VBA - Run a code every half an hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257985/outlook-vba-run-a-code-every-half-an-hour). The complications are what prompted me to suggest  a third-party spam solution.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, use inbox rules to automatically perform specific actions on emails that arrives in your inbox. So it is expected to have no effect on the emails in the Junk Email folder. If you really need it, you can refer to harrymc's suggestions.

In addition, I know that there is an [option](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-level-of-protection-in-the-junk-email-filter-e89c12d8-9d61-4320-8c57-d982c8d52f6b#:%7E:text=classified%20as%20junk.-,Just%20delete%20them!,-You%20can%20tell) in the outlook client to delete all suspected junk emails instead of moving them to the Junk Email folder. However, this will delete all suspicious emails, but not only emails with specific subject you mentioned. This may help you.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I saw the option of permanently deleting junk mail, but since I sometimes get useful mail in my Junk I don't really want to implement this.

Comment: Okay. By the way, if you always receive someone's emails and they are moved to Junk Email folder, it's suggested that you could add the sender to Safe Sender.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible because the mails come from a different address each time

Comment: If so, maybe you can try to set a lower level of Junk e-mail protection.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try that

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. Specifically, I marked 'no automatic filter' in the Outlook app in my laptop for the Junk Email settings, but spam is still going to the Junk Email, including the spam that I want to delete.